# Agents in 2d and 3d are not displayed in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

In my model, agents in 2d and 3d from the customers population are not displayed. For example, if you select in the soure block "Default population" - agents in 2d and 3d are displayed.

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmRIh.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St8j5.png)

And if you choose the "Customers" group in the soure block - agents in 2d and 3d are not displayed.

[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xKtD.png)
[image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEIlk.png)

What's wrong with the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the very hidden secrets of AnyLogic

The reason why you get this error is because you defined the agent without animation when you created it.

But the way to fix it is to click on the "show presentation" button... which you can find in the botton of the agent population properties:

[image: show presentation button]

Comment: I have one question. I have created a new parameter "money" for the agent and I write his random number of 1000 to 20,000. As in the sumMoney textbox, print out the sum of the 'money' parameter of all the agents in which work==true and education==true?

Comment: sumWhere(customers,c->c.money,c->c.work && c.education)

Comment: No. I need to find the amount for all time

Comment: For example, the patameter "money" of the first agent of 2000, the patameter "money" of the second agent 5500 and so on ...
The result should be 7500

Comment: that's exactly what I answered.. I repeat my answer: sumWhere(customers,c->c.money,c->c.work && c.education)